# Date object with time 24 hour format and start of date 00:00:000

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayjs

I have a situation where the date field in the database is in local time of different regions. So I need to do some aggregation and I only need to have start and end of a given date. I want the format to be like 2023-08-15 00:00:00.000 and at the same time it should be a javascript object. I tried to the following but it always ads the timezone, which I dont want. I am free to use any library if I available

```js
const cutoffDate = '2023-08-14';

var d = new Date(cutoffDate);
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
console.log(d);
```

However, this gives a bad result: 2023-08-13T07:00:00.000Z, instead it should have been 2023-08-14T00:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```js
const cutoffDate = '2023-08-14';

var d = new Date(cutoffDate);

console.log(d.toISOString());
```

to get `2023-08-14T00:00:00.000Z`. The format is called an [ISO 8601 format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

When you [create a Date object using a `dateString`, it uses `Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters), and [with a format like `"2023-08-14"`, it treats it as UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#using_date.parse).

Comment: I cannot convert it to string, it must be passed as Date object to prisma

Comment: well, `d` above is already a Date object